# Xamarin Android app crashes on Release mode

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Several months ago I updated Xamarin to 4.5.0.476 (Xamarin Android 7.3.1.2) and today, updating an App, I discovered that I cannot run my apk in release mode because it crashes when runs. And I can't understand why.

I tried to set all type of permissions on the android manifest.
Linker setting is *SDK Assembly only* but I also tried *None*.
I cleaned and rebuilt several times.
There's not conditional code that can fail on start-up.

Nothing, app always crashes when opening main activity.

Comment: Please share the crash logs, if you can. Also, are you using ProGuard and/or Multi-Dex?

Comment: No, I don't use Proguard nor multidex. How can I retrieve crash logs on Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @Danilo.NET Logcat: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/

Comment: Found on logcat this error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load monodroid from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Full image error here: https://ibb.co/nfWVDG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved! In Advanced Android Option **armeabi-v7a** architecture was unchecked, there was only **armeabi**. I switched option on and app starts without run into error.

Comment: `armeabi-v7a` is also checked for me but the app still crashes... any fix?

Comment: @Aousafrashid for me too. Have you fixed this?